# Backspace does nothing

Tags: insert-mode

I am on a Unixware 7.1 box and can't seem to get VI to backspace properly.  The current behavior is when you insert new characters and backspace over them, it will just shift the cursor to the left.  However, if I open a fresh file and do not type any new characters, the behavior of backspace is to do nothing at all.  The only time the cursor shifts is new files.  Here is my `.exrc`:

```
set ts=4
#set nocompatible
#set backspace=2
set bs=indent,eol,start
```

I also tried `set backspace=` instead of `bs=`.  As you can see I also tried the two commented out lines as well.  Here is what my `.profile`looks like:

```
stty intr "^c" erase "^?" swtch "^z" kill "^u"
```

The current behavior of backspace in a regular terminal session (in putty) with that `.profile` is to delete characters, so that aspect is working properly.  Any would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I had to put the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
map! <C-h> <BS>
```

Note! Different systems handle backspace differently. To find out what your backspace is getting mapped to, start vi and go into insert mode. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and then <kbd>Backspace</kbd>. Most likely vim will output something like `^H`. This means that Vi is not seeing backspace, but actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Once you figure out what Vi is seeing you can simply remap that to backspace as I did.

Comment: You might find `:help :fixdel` interesting.

Comment: I went into insert mode and did a Control + V and all it inserted was ^  When I hit backspace it inserted a ?  I then put map! <C-?> <BS> into my .exrc and it did not help.  Have I put the correct thing in my .exrc?

Comment: The <C-h> mapping means Ctrl+h. By the same token <C-?> means Ctrl+?. This is not quite what you want since VI didn't output a "^?". Which ALSO means Ctrl+?. Confusing, I know. Based on the context the notation changes. Since it output only a ? I will direct you to the same place that @romainl directed me. In `:help :fixdel` it says:
Note about Linux: By default the backspace key produces CTRL-?, which is wrong. You can fix is by putting this line in your rc.local:
echo "keycode 14 = BackSpace" | loadkeys.

Note, I haven't tried this as I'm not on a Linux machine ATM.

Comment: :help or :help :fixdel return "help: not an editor command".  If I login and press bs in terminal it will output ^? in VI when I hit backspace.  However even with it outpitting ^? in VI + the mapping, it still didn't delete.  To get to the help you are merely typing :help after hitting escape?  I think this machine is so old it may not have a help file.

Answer (score 1):

Following solution helped me to resolve Backspace issue on Ubuntu 19.04

create .exrc file in user home directory

and add following lines:

```
set nocompatible
map! <C-h> <BS>
set bs=indent,eol,start
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Welcome Abhi. Note that the common consensus is to use `.vimrc` (for vim) or `.init.rc` (for vimrc) not `.exrc`. Using `set nocompatible` is not necessary when you are using a `.vimrc` file (I don't know if that's the case with a `.exrc` file but that would be an argument not to use `.exrc`). And setting `bs` doesn't have an impact on OP's question. So this answer is really a duplicate of the currently accepted one.

Comment: Hi Knoble, You are correct. You can mark it as a duplicate. Intention was to convey the combination of above 3 lines worked for me. Already given answer is absolutely correct. However, somehow it didn't work me. Test both the solutions, may be first one works for most of people but it didn't work as a complete solution for me. Thanks